# Variable scopes in Go

Tags: go, scope

There is some behavior in Go that puzzles me since I first saw it: Using the net/http package one can define a handler

```
http.Handle("/foo", fooHandler)
```

now if you later call

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

then you might notice that the function http.Handle somehow managed to create a variable that (apparently) escaped from its scope (its scope being the http.Handle function).
Maybe I have a fundamental misconception about how scopes work in C like languages, but I always thought that the only ways in which a function can pass results to its caller is by

1. classical return which must then be saved in a variable by the caller
2. passing a pointer to a function as an argument and the function then manipulates the variable stored at the address saved inside that pointer

I believe that there also is a third option by using global variables, and my Google search points at this being the answer to my question. But even though I certainly don't know much about global variables (I always thought of them being quite confusing), my understanding has always been that you have to declare that variable **outside a function block**. So could the function http.Handle really declare a global variable that is "global enough" to be accessed from my main?

Can someone explain to my what happened there? And also if I am the only person being confused by this and if this is a style I should get comfortable with?

Comment: `http.Handle` registers the given handler in the package-level (similar to global) variable called `DefaultServeMux` which is declared [here](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.17.6#DefaultServeMux). And `http.ListenAndServe`, if passed `nil` as the second argument, will use `DefaultServeMux` to handle the incoming requests. All this is explicitly documented in package's documentation. To put it simply: `http.Handle` stores `fooHandler` in a global variable and `http.ListenAndServe` accesses `fooHandler` from the global variable.

Comment: The way you're thinking about scope is accurate,  you just conflate http internal state with your scope incorrectly as mkopriva points out.   You can keep thinking of state that way